# Q; Talend, find out which database recieves data from webservice

Tags: java, mysql, talend

I have a Talend Studio Data Intergration 6.2.1. job which is exported as .war, to be executed on a server as a webservice.

My question is, is there any way that I can find out which application calls my ws?

Note: I have 2 Java applications calling this ws with Axis but I don't know which one of them is calling it at a specific time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Search for "java - Rest - how get IP address of caller - Stack Overflow" or "java - Geting the IP Address Of A client For a webservice - Stack ..." on Stack Exchange.

Now, compare the IP with context variables to know the calling application.

Hope this help.